# How to make read() non-blocking and reset read()

Tags: c, select

So i made this function which acts like a countdown.I want to read a command while the countdown decreases. My big problem is making `read()` the wait for a input while countdown is decreasing.As you can see I tried using `select()` but after the first `printf("timeout.\n");` it stops trying to read. I made the show only once `timeout` or else it would go until countdown reached 0. I need to try read again.

```
int timer(int seconds) 
{
    time_t start, end;
    double elapsed;
    int opened=0; 
    char command[10];
    struct timeval tv;
    int fd_stdin,rv;
    fd_set rd;

    fd_stdin=fileno(stdin);

    FD_ZERO(&rd);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin),&rd);

    tv.tv_sec=5;
    tv.tv_usec=0;

    time(&start);  /* start the timer */

    do
    {
        time(&end);

        elapsed = difftime(end, start);

        if(fmod(elapsed,5)==0)
        {
            printf("Time remaining: %f minutes.\n", (seconds-elapsed)/60);
            sleep(1);
            if(opened==0)
            {
                printf("Use opentest to open your test.\n");
                opened=1;
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        int c;
        rv=select(fd_stdin+1,&rd,NULL,NULL,&tv);
        if(rv==-1)
        {
            perror("Error on select.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (rv==0 && c!=1)
        {
            printf("timeout.\n");
            rv=select(fd_stdin+1,&rd,NULL,NULL,&tv);
            c=1;
        }
        else 
        {
            c=0;
            read(fd_stdin,command,10);
        }
    }
    while(elapsed < seconds);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: to use the `fmod()` function , I compile like this: `gcc client.c -lm -o client.exe`. I don`t think this is the problem but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` modifies the `fd_set` upon exit to reflect which descriptors have been signaled.  You are not resetting the `fd_set` after each timeout.

Also, on some platforms, `select()` modifies the `timeval` structure to reflect how much time is remaining, so you would have to reset the `timeval` each time you call `select()` on those platforms.

Also, your `c` variable is declared inside the loop and is uninitialized. Move it outside the loop instead.

Try something more like this:

```
int timer(int seconds) 
{
    time_t start, end;
    double elapsed;
    int opened = 0; 
    char command[10];
    struct timeval tv;
    int fd_stdin, rv;
    fd_set rd;
    int c = 0;

    fd_stdin = fileno(stdin);

    time(&start);  /* start the timer */

    do
    {
        time(&end);

        elapsed = difftime(end, start);

        if (fmod(elapsed, 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("Time remaining: %f minutes.\n", (seconds-elapsed)/60);
            sleep(1);
            if (opened == 0)
            {
                printf("Use opentest to open your test.\n");
                opened = 1;
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        FD_ZERO(&rd);
        FD_SET(fd_stdin, &rd);

        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        rv = select(fd_stdin+1, &rd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (rv == -1)
        {
            perror("Error on select.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (rv == 0)
        {
            if (c != 1)
            {
                printf("timeout.\n");
                c = 1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            c = 0;
            read(fd_stdin, command, 10);
        }
    }
    while (elapsed < seconds);
    return 0;
}
```